# DeviceTwinClient when invokes getTags() method returns java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management

When invokes an iotHub query to get DevicetwinDevice of multiple devices:

```
SqlQuery sqlQuery = SqlQuery.createSqlQuery("*", SqlQuery.FromType.DEVICES, generateWhere(listDeviceIds), null);
            Query twinQueryCollection = twinClient.queryTwin(sqlQuery.getQuery());
            QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions();
            while (twinClient.hasNextDeviceTwin(twinQueryCollection)) {
                    deviceTwinList.add(twinClient.getNextDeviceTwin(twinQueryCollection));
            }
```

When later invokes getTags() from element, exception was throwed:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key cannot contain illegal unicode control characters '.', '$', ' '");
```

The problem is element inside tags contains a keys with $:

```
{"Session":"Sessio1",
"ManufacturingDate":"2019-0517T08:57:20.260+02:00[Europe/Madrid]",
"IV":"01.00",
"**$version**":1.0,
"Subtype":"-----",
"**$metadata**":{}
}
```

those elements on tag aren't mine. is it a SDK error? My code contains an error?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution of problem, after execute query, I get a list of DeviceTwinDevice. To getTags without exception I need to execute **twinClient.getTwin(deviceTwinDevice);**. Like this:

```
SqlQuery sqlQuery = SqlQuery.createSqlQuery("*", SqlQuery.FromType.DEVICES, generateWhere(listDeviceIds), null);
            Query twinQueryCollection = twinClient.queryTwin(sqlQuery.getQuery());
            QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions();
            while (twinClient.hasNextDeviceTwin(twinQueryCollection)) {
                    deviceTwinList.add(twinClient.getNextDeviceTwin(twinQueryCollection));
            }
            for (DeviceTwinDevice deviceTwinDevice : deviceTwinList) {
                **twinClient.getTwin(deviceTwinDevice);**
                if(!deviceTwinDevice.getTags().isEmpty()) {
                    -------------------------------------------------------
                }
```

getTwin() method remove $keys. In this case, I throw more than one message to Azure IotHub. The query and getTwin for individual device. I want to do the same in an unique  message with Azure IotHub. Is it Possible?